# Как остановить событие socket.io на сервере?

Tags: node.js, сокет, express, socket.io

Есть приложение на expressJS. Когда я перехожу на конкретную страницу, запускается событие на сервере и с помощью `setInterval` мы шлем клиенту какие-то данные. Но вот, пользователь закрывает страницу, а событие на сервере продолжает работать. Нужно как-то понимать, сколько клиентов подписано на текущее событие, и если ноль то останавливать `setInterval`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Отмена `setInterval`**

В дополнение к [`setInterval`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) есть [`clearInterval`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_clearinterval_intervalobject), позволяющая отменить выполнение:

```js
const intervalId = setInterval(/*...*/);  // Начинаем периодическое выполнение
clearInterval(intervalId);                // и останавливаем его.
```

<sup>Так же есть аналогичные функции для [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_cleartimeout_timeoutobject) и [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_clearimmediate_immediateobject).</sup>

**Определение ухода пользователя**

На каждое отключение пользователя соотвествующий ему сокет создаёт событие `disconnect`. 
Пример кода есть [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342548/socket-io-disconnect-event-isnt-fired).

**Всё вместе**

В простейшем случае — запоминай ID интервала и количество подписавшихся пользователей. Меняй количество при подписке или отписке от рассылки:

- подключение пользователя — `count += 1`;
- уход пользователя — `count -= 1`.

При каждом изменении, проверяй:

- `count` стал 0 — делай `clearInterval`;
- `count` был 0, а стал 1 — делай `setInterval`.

```js
let usersSubscribed = 0;
let intervalId = null;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  usersSubscribed += 1;
  if (usersSubscribed === 1)
    intervalId = setInterval(/*...*/);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    usersSubscribed -= 1;
    if (usersSubscrbied === 0)
      clearInterval(intervalId);
  });
});
```

Comment: Да это понятно. Но как понять сколько клиентов на конкретное событие подписаны? Или, я думал через `namespace` в socket.io сделать, но такой же вопрос, как понять, сколько клиентов у конкретного `namespace`? Или может есть смысл сделать это все через `room`?

Comment: @sanu0074 складывай сокеты в массив при подключении или подписке.

Comment: есть что вроде `onSubscribe`?

Comment: @sanu0074 есть список клиентов комнат http://stackoverflow.com/a/6967755

Comment: там же написано `NOTE: This Solution ONLY works with version prior to 1.0`